# "Переводы" названий языков программирования как синонимы оригинальных названий

Tags: обсуждение, метки, синонимы-меток

Уже на этапе бета-тестирования на сайте появились метки (tags) для языков программирования в двух вариантах: оригинальное название и русский "перевод".

Например, [c](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) и [си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8)

Теоретически могут появляться ещё и метки с разными вариантами транслитерации (что-то вроде "java / джава / ява").

Предлагаю ввести общее правило (рекомендацию) ***не транслитерировать*** названия технологий и создать ***[синонимы](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) для распространённых вариантов*** транслитераций.

---

Первым делом предлагаю сделать метку `си` синонимом `c` (латиницей).

Comment: Не то чтобы появились, а давно существовали. Но теперь у нас есть инструменты, чтобы навести порядок в метках.

Comment: В целом я соглашусь, что имена собственные (названия языков, библиотек, фреймворков, технологий) должны оставаться в оригинальном виде. Никакие "джава / ява" на мой взгляд не нужны.

Answer (score -3):

Дурацкая затея. jQuery теперь буде Джейкуаери, а HTML ЭйчТиЭмЕль?

Comment: Ну ладно вам так категорично. Вполне себе есть «паскаль», «форт», «ассемблер», «пролог», «хаскель». «Эйчтиэмэль» и правда никто не говорит.

Comment: [синонимы в обратную сторону работают](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms), например, если кто-то пишет `питон` при задаче вопроса, то система `python` автоматически подставляет. Вот примеры: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms

Comment: Так автор и предлагает НЕ транслитерировать. Если кто-то напишет "джейкуаери", произойдет автозамена на "jquery", ибо нефиг транслитерировать.